# Wait for API call before proceeding in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a problem with async and await, here I am trying to get te weather from a weather API but in my main function getWeather I want the code to wait for my http.get to be done before proceeding. At the moment, as you can imagine, the output on console is first "test" then "In London temperature is ...". I tried quite a lot of different ways of using promises and async/await but none of them work...
Does someone know how to get the weather printed first and then "test"? Thx

```
var http = require('http');

function printMessage(city, temperature, conditions){
  var outputMessage = "In "+ city.split(',')[0] +", temperature is 
"+temperature+"°C with "+conditions;
  console.log(outputMessage);
}

function printError(error){
  console.error(error.message);
}


function getWeather(city){

var request = http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+ city +"&APPID=[API_ID]&units=metric", function(response){

  var body = "";
  response.on('data', function(chunk){
    body += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function(){
    if (response.statusCode === 200){
      try{
        var data_weather = JSON.parse(body);
        printMessage(city, data_weather.main.temp,   data_weather.weather[0].description);

      } catch(error) {
        console.error(error.message);
      }
    } else {
      printError({message: "ERROR status != 200"});
    }

  });

});
console.log('test');
}

getWeather("London");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap `request` in a Promise:

```
function requestAsync() {
    return new Promise((resolver, reject) => {
        // request
        http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&APPID=[API_ID]&units=metric", function (response) {
            var body = "";
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                body += chunk;
            });

            response.on('end', function () {
                if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                    try {
                        var data_weather = JSON.parse(body);
                        printMessage(city, data_weather.main.temp, data_weather.weather[0].description);
                        // request will done here!
                        resolver();
                        return;
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error(error.message);
                    }
                } else {
                    printError({ message: "ERROR status != 200" });
                }
                // request was failed!
                reject();
            });
        });
    })
}
```

and using async/await to call `requestAsync`:

```
async function getWeather(city) {
    await requestAsync();

    console.log('test');
}

getWeather("London");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getWeather = function(city){
    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject){
        try{
            var dataUrl = await http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+ city +"&APPID=[API_ID]&units=metric";
            resolve(dataUrl);
        } catch(error) {
            return reject(error);
        }
    })
};
```